# Unexpected behaviour of cin for bool

Tags: c++

I am trying to take input in bool type array using `cin`. If input is given like `0111100010001000` it instead of running for all iteration ( In my input it is 16 ) it terminates and print some garbage values, But if input is given like `0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0` it works as expected.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>

#define FRND 2001

using namespace std;

int main(){
    bool mutualFriend[FRND][FRND];
    int noOfFriends = 0;
    cin >> noOfFriends;
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfFriends ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfFriends; j++){
            cin >> mutualFriend[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfFriends ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfFriends; j++){
            cout << mutualFriend[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`cin.clear()` can solve my problem.

Please explain why loops are skipped in the first scenario.

Comment: Incidentally, if the size of each row is known at compile time, you can use an array of `std::bitset`, for which a suitable extraction operator is actually provided.

Answer (score 3):

The way `operator>>` parses input for a `bool` argument is specified in §22.4.2.1.2 [facet.num.get.virtuals]/p6 of the standard:

> If `(str.flags()&ios_base::boolalpha)==0` then input proceeds as it
>   would for a `long` except that if a value is being stored into `val`,
>   the value is determined according to the following: If the value to be
>   stored is `0` then `false` is stored. If the value is `1` then `true`
>   is stored. Otherwise `true` is stored and `ios_base::failbit` is
>   assigned to err.

Therefore, if you give it `0111100010001000` it will first try to parse it as a `long`, giving you a large number (that obvious isn't `1`). Then the second step of the processing causes `true` to be stored into the `bool` and  `failbit` to be set.

Comment: If `011100010001000 > LONG_MAX` then it may fail before even getting to the second step (I think)

Comment: @MattMcNabb It will fail, but it will still get to the second step - the `long` conversion would set `failbit` and store `LONG_MAX`, which, being neither 0 nor 1, will cause `true` be stored and `failbit` to be set - again. So there's no difference in practice.

Answer (score 1):

cin has space as default delimiter so when you do read from the value 10101.. it regards it as just a big int.

Instead use .get() to read a single character

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfFriends ; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < noOfFriends; j++){
        mutualFriend[i][j] = (cin.get() == '1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

T.C. has explained the way streaming in to a `bool` works, summarily a `long` is consumed, `0` -> `false`, `1` -> `true`, otherwise `true` but with `failbit` set.

For general numeric input, C++ has `std::dec` for decimal input, `std::oct` for octal (base 8), `std::hex` for hexadecimal (base 16), but strangely nothing for binary.  It is not possible to read a multi-digit binary representation of a number directly into an integral type.

What you'll have to do is read a character at a time, then convert to binary yourself:

```
`char c;`

...

    if (cin >> c && (c == '0' || c == '1'))
        mutualFriend[i][j] == c != '0';
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("failure to parse binary digit from stream");
```